# How to get the reference of a table in MS Word by using bookmark in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

[image]

I have a table in a MS Word document as above. And I want to add some rows programmatically.
To do this, I add a bookmark for this table (as you can see, in the first empty row). But now, I cannot get the reference to this table. I have a function as below, but it always return null. Why?

Note: I cannot use a index to get this table, because the index may change.

```
    public Word.Table GetTable(string bookmarkTable)
    {
        try
        {
            object bkObj = bookmarkTable;
            if (wApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmarkTable) == true)
            {
                return wApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bkObj) as Word.Table;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's probably because Bookmarks.get_Item gets you a Bookmark object, not a Table object. Try getting the Range from the Bookmark, then get the first Table from that Range.

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure that was the only reason, but now you have confirmed I have posted an Answer. We can get rid of these comments now...

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarks.get_Item gets you a Bookmark object, not a Table object.

Get the Range from the Bookmark, then get the first Table from that Range.